# Create MYSQL multi-column view from key val table?

Tags: mysql, view

I've got a simple MYSQL table that has **id**, **field_key**, **field_val** columns. My goal is to create a multi-column table or view based on the field_key data.

Basically,

```
**id,key,val**
1,fname,joe
1,lname,smith
2,fname,sally
2,lname,smith
```

*into*

```
**id,fname,lname**
1,joe,smith
2,sally,smith
```

Currently, I am using a queries to get the DISTINCT id's, and all the DISTINCT field_keys. Then, in PHP, I am looping through the id's and then inner-looping the field_keys to populate the table: SELECT field_val FROM pair_table where id = :id and field_key = :field_key

Can this be done as a view inside of MYSQL?

Answer (score 0):

One method for doing this is conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when key = 'fname' then val end) as fname,
       max(case when key = 'lname' then val end) as lname
from table t
group by id;
```